# ¿Como implementar Quicksort Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, quicksort

tengo una duda y es como podría implementar el algoritmo Quicksort para ordenar alfabeticamente una lista de nombres por ejemplo: Marcos Calderon, Matias Ruiz, Daniela Goretti, Marcos Hurtado, Marcos Phillips.

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que le des un vistazo a como formular una buena pregunta, para que no vayan a cerrarte la misma. Ahora si ya has implementado un QuickSort para números, te darás cuenta que la lógica será la misma, pero deberás hacer uso del CompareTo de la clase String, para hacer las comparaciones entre cadenas de caracteres. **Si eres nuevo en programación, te recomiendo dar una leída a algoritmos recursivos y a las funciones de los Strings **

Answer (score 1):

Java posee clases para hacer esas operaciones. No es necesario reinventar la rueda.

Ejemplo. Definimos una lista tipo String y la llenamos sin un orden estricto. Una vez que este llena ordenarla usando el método sort de la clase Collections.

```
 java.util.ArrayList<String> nombres = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
    nombres.add(0,"Zara");
    nombres.add(1,"Ines");
    nombres.add(2,"Genaro");
    nombres.add(3,"Ana");
    java.util.Collections.sort(nombres);

    for(String nombre: nombres){
     System.out.println("Hola, "+nombre);
    }
```

Salida:
[Ana, Genaro, Ines, Zara]

Comment: Si lo explicarás harías más simple entender lo que aportas, además que no es necesario reinventar la rueda si ya comprendemos cómo funciona en caso contrario plantear hacer un algoritmo no estaría mal